# {nativescript} indexOf array

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have an array like below. When I using `this.itemsgroupcustomer.indexOf("Perorangan")`, it return -1. I don't have any idea why this is wrong. Please help.

```
viewModel.itemsgroupcustomer = [
        {title: "Perusahaan"},
        {title: "Perorangan"}
    ];
```

Comment: Because the array does not contain an element that is a `Perorangan` string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use findIndex method -

```
viewModel.itemsgroupcustomer.findIndex(x=>x.title==='Perorangan');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead, it returns the element that passes the test:

```js
const arr = [
  {title: "Perusahaan"},
  {title: "Perorangan"}
]
console.log(arr.find(el => el.title === 'Perorangan'))
```

You can then use the return value to find its index on the array

```js
const arr = [
  {title: "Perusahaan"},
  {title: "Perorangan"}
]
const filteredElement = arr.find(el => el.title === 'Perorangan')
console.log(arr.indexOf(filteredElement))
```

---

UPDATE:

As user @zerkms has pointed there's a built in method that does the above in a single step, it's [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const arr = [
  {title: "Perusahaan"},
  {title: "Perorangan"}
]
console.log(arr.findIndex(el => el.title === 'Perorangan'))
```

Comment: There is an `Array.prototype.findIndex` there

Comment: many thanks @mauricio, how does this array things working? sometimes i'm lost in array world. here is my oneline code `this.itemsgroupcustomer.indexOf( this.itemsgroupcustomer.find(el => el.title === "Perorangan"))`. It's return 1. yay